# Encoding URI if part of the GET Search

Tags: postman

I've tried the below with and without encoding -- with the error received in *italics* immediately below each GET below.

Can URLs be in the GETs of a postman?

No Encoding--
https://api.example.com/foo/bar/user_id::https://bob.alice.com/id/9869869696/9797097GGGG
*Error: Invalid protocol: https:/stg.api.ubc.ca/person-hub/v2/persons/user_id::https:*

Encoded--
https://api.example.com/foo/bar/user_id%3A%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fbob.alice.com%2Fid%2F9869869696%2F9797097GGGG
*Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.example.com*